# Does the JavaScript that Google Analytics Experiments adds slow down alternate versions, and how could I measure this?

Tags: google-analytics, javascript, page-speed, a-b-testing

I am using Content Experiments in Google Analytics to test three different landing pages. This uses JavaScript on the initial page to load the alternates.

Would the additional JavaScript add to the load time for alternative versions, and if so how can I measure this?

Comment: I edited this to be less subjective and hence on-topic. Feel free to modify if something else was intended.

Comment: Thanks! Lousy excuse: I was trying to enter this before going to bed and had to use a cr@ppy touchscreen tablet, making typing a royal pain.

Comment: In my experience it most definitely does add to the load time.  Consider looking at Chrome Developer Tools "Network" interface for render time comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Negligible:  about 30 ms to 100 ms**

I found the Pingdom page speed test to be easier to use than the Chrome tool.

Here's what I found:

1. Loading /index.php and then having the google .js experiment code reload a second page:
   total time: 1.37 s (avg of ( 1.40, 1.79  , .93 s(avg)) s
2. Loading the secondary page (bypassing the index.php and the google .js experiment code:
   total time : 1.28 (avg of (1.84 (.833  1.52, .961)

So looks like about .1 seconds. Fairly insignificant.

3. In looking at the actual load progression it looks like the delay is more like .3s

It looks like the *overhead* of loading the GA Experiment code is about 30ms (avg of  20  37 40)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using chrome developer tool, load the page and view the Timeline tab in dev tools. Do this for each version of the page and see if the variations are taking longer to load.